# Extending View Class

Tags: java, android, inheritance

I need to extend the Button view class, so I can add some properties to store data (I can't use setTag() cause I need to store more than one variable). I'm doing this:

```
public class ButtonExtended extends Button{
private String thumb;
private String desc;
private String key;

public void setDesc(String desc) {
    this.desc = desc;
}

public void setKey(String key) {
    this.key = key;
}

public void setThumb(String thumb) {
    this.thumb = thumb;
}

public String getDesc() {
    return desc;
}

public String getKey() {
    return key;
}

public String getThumb() {
    return thumb;
}

public ButtonExtended(Context context) {
    super(context);
}
```

}

The problem is that in the OnClick Listener of the extended button class, I'm not allowed to use the newly created methods:

```
private View.OnClickListener ButtonClicked = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        v.getThumb(); //This is not allowed

    }
};
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: and this `((ButtonExtended)v.getThumb())` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast it to the custom class that you have made.

```
private View.OnClickListener ButtonClicked = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ButtonExtended buttonView = (ButtonExtended) v;
        buttonView.getThumb(); //This is not allowed

    }
};
```